# Monitor a process

Tags: linux, process

Is there a way I a process can be monitor and if it were to die, can a script be called which in turn will bring the process back up ?

Comment: You might get better answers to this on serverfault.com

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/637470/monitor-a-process-using-monit-in-ubuntu

Comment: Instead of putting a question "on hold as off-topic", why not just move it to Super User or Server Fault where it belongs?

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  if pgrep myprocess  >/dev/null ;then
     echo "up"
  else
     echo "down"
     /path/to/myprocess &
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

or you could remove the while loop and sleep and put the script in a cron job set to run every minute

Answer (score 2):

monit.

http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: thanks :) looks like it will be perfect for me.

Comment: monit does not provide graphs/statistics for a process over a period of time right?

Comment: just a pointer. mmonit comes with AGPL license

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one of these a while ago called [relight](http://github.com/ghewgill/relight). There also exist more robust solutions, but this one is simple and works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is have the initial parent do the monitoring. EG,

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  cmd
  # When you get here the process has died.  start
  # the loop again and restart it
done
```

This script is liable to be killed so you might want
to trap signals, but the same will be true of any
monitor that you might write.  You will probably
also want to insert a delay if cmd is terminating
immediately, or add some logging (call logger
after you call cmd).  There's no need to get fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [command](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) that you specify in a simple [configuration file](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) can start, monitor, and restart a process that unexpectedly dies.

Consider the following Supervisor configuration file fragment in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/forever.conf` which displays the date and time every second:

```
[program:forever]
command=/bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo "Current time is `date`"; sleep 1; done;'
```

Program `forever` starts with PID 15474:

```
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/fire$ sudo supervisorctl status forever
forever                          RUNNING   pid 15474, uptime 0:00:17
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/fire$ sudo supervisorctl tail forever
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:10 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:11 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:12 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:13 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:14 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:15 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:16 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:17 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:18 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:19 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:20 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:21 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:22 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:23 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:24 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:25 EDT 2017
```

Kill the `forever` process and Supervisor restarts it automatically with new process ID 15760:

```
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/fire$ sudo kill 15474
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/fire$ sudo supervisorctl status forever
forever                          RUNNING   pid 15760, uptime 0:00:02
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/fire$ sudo supervisorctl tail forever
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:21 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:22 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:23 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:24 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:25 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:26 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:27 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:28 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:29 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:30 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:31 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:32 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:33 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:34 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:35 EDT 2017
Current time is Fri Jul  7 17:11:36 EDT 2017
```

Comment: I expanded my answer.  I now think it's one of the best answers overall.  However, even in its original form, my answer was no more lacking in context than one which recommends Monit (see stackoverflow.com/a/2354030/107158).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SysV system (not Upstart), you can put the process do respawn at inittab.

Just edit your /etc/inittab file and add a line like this:

proc:12345:respawn:/path/to/process

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways of getting the task done:

1. As suggested by others - Run a script to check if process is running, restart the process if not running. To check you if process is running or not you can use `pgrep <process name> | wc -l`
2. Use [watch command](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/watch/) to run a script after some interval to check if process is running, if not then restart the process
3. Create a parent process, that will always look for the child process, if child process crashes or stops, parent will be notified, then restarts new process.

Answer (score 0):

[systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) is a sophisticated process manager available on most major Linux distributions.